# Why does Mod operator returns the first number when the second number is larger than the first?

Tags: c#, modulo

I hope I'm not making a stupid question but, I can't find any good explanation on this result:

`35 % 36` is equal to `35`

https://www.google.com.ph/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=35%20%25%2036

But if I divide the two numbers, `35 / 36` the result is: `0.97222222222` where I assume that the remainder would be `97`.

Can anyone explain this?

Comment: http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/sets/select/dm_mod.html and http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/54363.html should give you some insight.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> When we divide 13 % 3 it gives  1 (the remainder)

similarly when we do 35 % 36  it will give the first number as remainder, as the dividend is less than the divider.

when you are `dividing 35/36, integer division will give you 0 quotient.`
Float division will give you the fraction value, and the  fraction value is the remainder part.

> 13/3 = 4.33333  = 4 * 3 + (0.333)* *3
>                   =(integer quotient)* divider + remainder.

Answer (score 4):

The result of `35 % 36` is equivalent to dividing 35 by 36, and returning the remainder. Since 36 goes into 35 exactly 0 times, you're left with a remainder of 35.

Similarly, let's assume you do `7 % 3`. In this example, 3 goes into 7 twice and you're left with a remainder of 1. So `7 % 3 == 1`.

---

I don't have the source code for the operation, but you could mimic it (I'm sure this isn't as efficient as whatever's built in!) with a small function like this:

```
public static class MyMath
{
    public static int Mod(this int operand1, int operand2)
    {
        while (operand1 >= operand2)
            operand1 -= operand2;

        return operand1;
    }
}
```

And then call it like this:

```
var remainder1 = 7.Mod(3);    // 1
var remainder2 = 35.Mod(36);  // 35
```

Comment: So you mean, by default if the 1st number is less than the second, then it will return the first number? Can you please find for me the code for this. I want to understand on how it was done by code. Thanks!

Comment: Ahh, I get it... Since 36 does not fit with 35 therefore 35 is still a remainder.. But if you could point me to the internal code, that would be great. Thanks anyway. :)

Answer (score 0):

mod gives you the reminder of an integer division. 36 fits 0 times in 35 so 
35 / 36 is 0 and has a reminder of 35 which is the result of mod